# Update all object fields with a same value in a Groovy map

Tags: groovy

I have an Object in Groovy like:

```
class Person {
  def name
  def age
}
```

And a collection of persons stored in a map:

```
Person a = new Person(name: 'A', age:29)
Person b = new Person(name: 'B', age:15)

Map persons = ['1':a, '2':b]
```

I'm trying to update the age field for all persons, I know that I can do something like:

```
persons.each{ k,v -> v.age=0 }
```

But, I was wondering if is there another way to do it without iterating the entire map. As you can see, all persons should have the same value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

```
persons.values()*.age = 0
```